# Makefile: no rule to make target, needed by error

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile and I'm getting an error:

```
CXX=clang++ $(CXXFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -O2

OFILES = wordPuzzle.o hashTable.o timer.o

main:  $(OFILES)
       $(CXX) $(OFILES)
clean:
       -rm *.o

wordPuzzle.o: wordPuzzle.cpp
hashTable.o: hashTable.cpp hashTable.h
timer.o: timer.cpp timer.h
```

The error message says:

> No rule to make target 'wordPuzzle.cpp', needed by 'wordPuzzle.o'.

Comment: Are you sure workPuzzle.cpp is in the same folder than the Makefile ? I think `make` cannot find the file. You can place it in the same folder, or put the path to its folder in the Makefile variable called `VPATH`

Answer (score 0):

The linker will produce the file a.out. put "-o $@" in the recipe  for linking